# how to include the option of change password in mahapps metro ShowMessageAsync

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Is there an option of chnage password in ShowMessageAsync dialog in mahapps. Or is there a way to add a custom button or hyperlink to this dialogue upon which i can open another custom window with change password options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the existing message dialog but create a custom dialog. Just create your dialog inheriting `UserControl` and call

```cs
var customDialog = new CustomDialog {
    Title = "Your title",
    Content = new YourCustomDialog()
};
await window.ShowMetroDialogAsync(customDialog);
```

You can find a more complex example in the [sample application](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/6786e2c73490bf4e3db73e977ba71ec951c41516/src/MahApps.Metro.Samples/MahApps.Metro.Demo/MahApps.Metro.Demo.Shared/MainWindowViewModel.cs#L472-L484).

Comment: i have used the user control to create YourCustomDialog(). I call ShowMetroDialogAsync(customDialog) from my main window. then once this opens, i dont understand how to close this dialog using the close button present on the user control (YourCustomDialog).